# Replace view HTML

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular multi-step form in a modal window. It has a few different views and works great but at the end of it I just want to display a tiny snippet of HTML along the lines of 'Thank you, we will be in touch shortly'

However, I thought about creating a view for this with a partial but it seems incredibly over-engineered for what it is. Is there any way in angular of just replacing the view with that sentence without creating a whole new view? This will be called from a function in the final controller

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-show` and `ng-hide` to do this in your view. Suppose if your view is no longer needed you can hide it and show the Thank you snippet at its place by using `ng-show`.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-switch` is what you are looking for.

From the docs:

> "The directive itself works similar to ngInclude, however, instead of
>   downloading template code (or loading it from the template cache),
>   ngSwitch simply choses one of the nested elements and makes it visible
>   based on which element matches the value obtained from the evaluated
>   expression."

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch

Answer (score 0):

you can this code, if you have one area of content

```
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

good method you can find in [LINK](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js//urls-routing-and-partials/client-side-routing-with-hashbang-urls.html)